# EntityFramework. Remove all rows then add new. Async

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework, asynchronous

I'm running a CSV import into a SQL db via an ASP.NET MVC app.

I'm iterating all rows in the CSV, creating an equivalent entity for each and adding each one to the current context.

If there is at least one row to add then I want to remove all existing rows from the table being written to, then commit the new entities.

My question is whether it's safe to call `ExecuteSqlCommandAsync` and not await the result before I then call `await db.SaveChangesAsync();` like so:

```
db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync("delete from tblName");
await db.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Or should I `await` the delete call before I make the save changes call? In which case I may as well make the calls to the non async versions?

I'm currently not awaiting it and everything appears to be working as expected on local (practically no latency) i.e. the existing data is being removed and new data added. My concern is whether there is something else I should consider when the solution is deployed and the web server and SQL server aren't necessarily on the same box.

Answer (score 1):

As per [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189835.aspx):

> By default, a DELETE statement always acquires an exclusive (X) lock on the table it modifies, and holds that lock until the transaction completes.

This means that the save action will wait until the  delete action has finished, even though the latter is started async. So, since you await the save call, in fact you also await the delete call.

I think I'd prefer to await the delete call explicitly (or don't call it async) because you might want to respond to any errors it raises (like not executing the save action but writing a log instead).

Side note: consider using `TRUNCATE TABLE`.

Answer (score 1):

EF does not support concurrent usage of the same objects. This is not safe. There are now multiple threads writing to the same EF objects here which is not safe unless documented otherwise.

Even if this was safe with EF there would be no guarantee that the delete has even started when the save begins.

Error handling is also missing.

I don't see why you would want to do this. What benefit would this provide? Certainly no more throughput. Latency also is not reduced because the delete must complete before the save begins.